# Is the 'sister' question on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

I suspect we've all seen [My sister absolutely refuses to learn math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/416226/33079) by now - it's lodged at the top of the Stack Exchange hot questions list, it's been tweeted, it's got 27k views and hundreds of votes, etc etc.

But what I'm not clear on is **whether it's on topic**.

In the [on-topic-ness FAQ](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it's not in any of the off-topic groups, BUT also not in any of the on-topic groups. I'm inclined to consider this makes it *off* topic, but I see [it only stayed closed for four hours](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/416226/revisions) after it was for that reason closed, suggesting that there is significant disagreement.

Personally I could see it *perhaps* falling under "Understanding mathematical concepts and theorems", but only if it was the *learner* coming here to ask for help. The question as it stands is a *teaching* question, and therefore more suited to the (currently still in Area 51) sites [Education](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50826/education) or (if relevant, which I think it might be) [Homeschooling](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53746/homeschooling). The question's own tl;dr asks quite explicitly **How do you teach..**; and indeed not even "how do you teach [mathematical concept]" but rather "how do you teach someone who doesn't want to learn". This isn't about math. Relevant comments and answers would be respectively about the teaching relationship, and pedagogy in general.

Bearing in mind that *popularity alone* is not considered a sufficient reason for a post's existence at a Stack Exchange site, why is this one still here?

<sub><sup>I did flag to this effect, which was marked helpful, but I want to know if/why this is considered an appropriate question for MSE</sup></sub>

Comment: Historically, math.SE has always had a soft spot for pedagogy questions. Nevertheless, it might indeed be time to review if we still want questions like these.

Comment: I had the very same thought when I saw the question. I refused to contribute to the effect by adding an answer. Unfortunately, I have been on the page for the past four hours, commenting and replying. I don't really think these questions are such a good idea, as they draw interest, not to mention vitality and energy (mine!) from the rest of Math SE. They are also unanswerable, and likely to provoke endless debate, just as this one has done.

Comment: Such questions are perhaps borderline, but they’re a minuscule fraction of the total. Unless that changes, which seems unlikely, it’s a waste of time and energy to worry or complain about them, serving no useful purpose. Relevant answers are obviously about both teaching **and** mathematics; the two are inseparably mixed in this question.

Comment: If we allow questions like the one referenced here, it doesn't seem fair to close something like this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400535/can-we-get-just-3-from-pi though. Despite being a little silly, it was fun, and gave opportunity to show fluency with and flexibility of mathematical notation.

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I just read the comments on the original question, regarding 3 and pi. While the answers were fun, the question didn't make much sense. Moderators made the correct decision in closing that question, I must regretfully concede.

Comment: @FeralOink: This one does not appear to have provoked endless debate. Rather, it has stimulated quite a few good to decent suggestions and a moderate amount of what I consider fairly irrelevant but harmless chaff.

Comment: @Brian They happen to be among the minuscule fraction of questions that tend to radiate over the SE network and the internet, and thus have heavy influence on the image of MSE to the outside world. Since this image is skewed from what MSE is actually about, some effort to correct this discrepancy is IMO certainly warranted.

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I remain to be convinced that MSE has much of an image at all outside of SE and MO.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I have poor judgement about what is too much irrelevant and harmless chaff. I enjoy that sort of thing, a lot. I should just wander back to Money SE now, and answer some practical questions about small business taxes, or Quicken.

Comment: @FeralOink: *shudder* Better you than I! :-)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott MSE **DOES** have an image, and impact, outside of SE and MO! Much more than you realize! Google and Microsoft are very aware of SO, though maybe less so of MSE.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Scary: *Trouble getting revisions to Accounts Receivable to update in yearly financial statements in Quicken, help please?* especially since Quicken hasn't been supported by the developer since 2005, yet remains in use by many people, globally... Also: Questions about how to file IRS 1099 forms for child laborers.

Comment: Today, a first-time visitor to Math.SE will be shown following questions, to tell the visitor what this site is about: *My sister refuses to learn math*, *My son's Sum of Some is beautiful*, *surface area of a normal chicken egg*, *What is −i exactly?*, *Which one is bigger: 35,043×25,430 or 35,430×25,043?*, *Theorems' names that don't credit the right people*, *Why is 987654321/123456789 = 8.0000000729?*, *Is there a great mathematical example for a 12-year-old?*, *What is a proof?*, *If $n^2$ is even, then $n$ is even*, *Why do the French count so strangely?*... **sigh**

Comment: (To clarify: above I listed top questions on the front page as it shown to first-time visitors, in the order the questions appeared.)

Comment: @user79365, should've included a screenshot for maximum impact... ;)

Comment: @Ｊ.M. [Screenshot here](http://i.imgur.com/PKurh4e.png). To be fair, the list of questions is preceded on the screen by the most popular tags. They will tell the visitor that the site is not all about children's math experiences: there's some calculus and linear algebra homework, too. Sweet.

Comment: @user79365, I wasn't expecting you to indulge me, but thanks. :D Daamn... the "hot questions only" might work for SO, but it's certainly not a good fit here. (And now I see that KCd in another thread had a similar complaint.) On the brighter side, at least this "feature" wasn't rolled out during the time of the Batman question...

Comment: My opinion is this: There is nothing wrong with this question. Rather, the discussion should be that there are so many soft questions going about and what should be done about this. I do not think this specific question should be closed because it has generated so much interest - the community decides what is appropriate, and the community has chosen! However, I think we should be wary of soft questions, and I maybe wonder if we should try to nip them in the bud more often.........

Comment: @user1729 Even the network founder blogged about the [bikeshed effect](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/03/procrastination-and-the-bikeshed-effect.html), relating it to procrastination. There's a query that identifies [bikeshed questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/6961/bikeshed-questions) on math.SE with frightening accuracy.

Comment: @user79365 I am not entirely sure what your point is. Are you trying to say that there should be a blanket ban on soft questions? I disagree. I would perhaps hypothesise that there is something similar to the bikeshed question: The *car paint* question. You see, people can give lots of interesting and wild reasons why your car should be painted colour X. But if you move to Africa you will soon realise that X=white is what you want. My point: A seemingly useless question has a time and a place. If they are never asked then someone will end up driving around the Sahara, roasting in a black car..

Comment: @user1729 I was reacting to "[why] there are so many soft questions going about" with Atwood's observation: people using SE to procrastinate love such questions. ... No, I don't want to ban such questions -- I would like to cut the positive feedback loop in SE software that blows them out of proportion. I supported [Mad Scientist's suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183109/224469) to this effect, but it's clearly going nowhere.

Comment: @user79365 Ah, right, I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's on topic.  The question is about how to teach **mathematics** to a student lacking motivation.  I don't think that this is the same, as you suggest,  as how to teach to someone who doesn't want to learn in general.

Mathematics admits (and, in my opinion, *requires*) a different pedagogy than other subjects.  This is due, among other things, to the cumulative nature of the material $-$ an issue mentioned explicitly in the question.  As such the discussion is *specific to mathematics*, which makes it on topic.

Furthermore, mathematicians [can be very opinionated](http://www.maa.org/devlin/lockhartslament.pdf) about how math should be taught, so as a place where the general public can interface with advanced students of mathematics, I consider Math StackExchange to be the perfect venue for this type of discussion.

Comment: It’s also worth pointing out that the popularity of the question and consequent volume of answers and discussion mean that the topic has been pretty thoroughly addressed, and the general nature of the topic means that much of the discussion is quite widely applicable. I seriously question the value of canonical answers to purely mathematical questions, since from the student’s point of view the devil is very often in the specific details, but I think that for the foreseeable future this question now has something akin to a canonical answer that is genuinely useful.